# Why does an Iterator not go up when called twice?

Tags: java, iterator

The following program iterates over a String. The Iterator cuts it between the whitespaces and returns each word. I use a for each loop to use the iterable string and within that loop I iterate again over the same string using the same iterator as in the outer loop. The output is:
hello hello
hello 0
hello 2 
etc...

But it should be:
hello 0
hello 2
...
because the outer loop already increased the counter of the iterator. So I think I'm missing something in this picture about iterators work...
any help appreciated!

The code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TopLevelClass{

    public TopLevelClass(final String... strings) {
        for(String nextSentence : strings){
            IterableSentence itSentence = new IterableSentence(nextSentence);
            for(String nextWord : itSentence){
                for(String nextWord2 : itSentence){
                    System.out.println(nextWord + " " + nextWord2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        final TopLevelClass sceneData = new TopLevelClass("hello 0 2");
    }

    private class IterableSentence implements Iterable<String>{

        private final String sentence;

        private IterableSentence(String sentence){
            this.sentence = cleanup(sentence);
        }

        private IterableSentence(IterableSentence itSentence){
            this.sentence = itSentence.sentence;
        }

        @Override public Iterator<String> iterator(){
            return new SentenceIterator();
        }

        private class SentenceIterator implements Iterator<String>{

            private final String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
            private int counter = 0;

            @Override public boolean hasNext(){
                return counter < words.length;
            }

            @Override public String next(){
                //System.out.println("called");
                return words[counter++].replaceAll("\\s+","");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: btw: I kicked the cleanup() method out of the code to make it more readable... so just assume this.sentence = sentence; in the constructor.

Comment: Did you consider just looping of ther `String[]` that is the result of `String.split()`? You could also use a Java 8 Stream on it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Works fine for me. It prints: `hello hello
hello 0
hello 2
0 hello
0 0
0 2
2 hello
2 0
2 2`

Comment: This is just a practice for university @Tichodroma. alfasin this is not what I want. I thought that the second loop uses the same iterator as the outer loop thus the next word after hello hast to be 0. then hello 2 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop calls `iterator()` on `IterableSentence` so you end up with two independent iterators.

If I understand what you really want to do then iterators are not the way t go and the easiest thing to do would be to use nested loops.

Comment: Thanks @MrWiggles. But what do I need to do if I don't want two independet rather just one iterator that keeps going in the second loop where it has stopped in the first loop?

Comment: That wont do what you think it will do - the inner loop will run until the end of the iterator so your outer loop would only get invoked once